# Отправка AT команд на COM-порт через командную строку Windows 10?

Tags: windows, cmd, com-порт, at

Через программу HyperTerminal все AT команды работают. Все ок. Модем выполняет звонки на указанный номер. Но вот через cmd все глухо. При отправке команды "echo ATD+48*********; >> COM9" ноль реакции (модем на 9-м ком порте).
Есть какие-то идеи в чем проблема?
Я хочу создать .bat файл в котором будет скрипт из нескольких команд. Только сначала нужно чтобы модем принимал AT команды через командную строку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через plink работает. Но вот ка завершить команду? Начать вводить новую возможно только после нажатия Ctrl+C. Я пробовал через bat-файл - результат тотже. Следующие команды после "echo at......." не выполняютса.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>win+r</kbd> (выполнить)

```
cmd /k echo AT_OGPS=2 >COM8
```

для портов старше 9:

```
cmd /k echo AT_OGPS=2 >\\.\COM18
```